# Integrating vectors with python

Tags: python, vector, integration

This may be more of a maths question but i don't know how to program it in python
I need to integrate a function of this form:

```
(r1 + r2)**j * (r1 - r2)**k * (numpy.abs(r_1 - r_2))**m * numpy.exp(-Z*(r1+r2) / (k * r0)
```

with respect to r1 and r2 between 0 and infinity. j, k and m are going to vary but are integer numbers, defined before the integration so they shouldn't matter too much. k and r0 are also constants defined before the integration is preformed.

I am trying to use scipy.integrate.dblquad. However the problem is that r_1 and r_2 are vectors, i.e. (x, y, z), and then the modulus of r1 - r2 is taken. Is there any way to tell python that these are vectors and it needs to integrate them as vectors?

hopefully i have explained my problem ok. Thank you

Comment: Is the second term `(|r_1|-|r_2|)**k` or `|r_1 - r_2|**k`? Similarly, is the first term `|r_1 + r_2|**j` or `(|r_1| + |r_2|)**j? (the vertical bars indicate moduli).

Comment: What does it mean for `r` to be between 0 and infinity? Is that the whole positive octant, or just the line `x = y = z`. Once you've defined that, you should try to rewrite the function in other coordinates ((x, y, z) or eg (r, phi, theta)) and integrate that.

Comment: If you're integrating over all space and `r_1` and `r_2` are vectors, you actually have 6 coordinates (Cartesian `x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2`). Look into `scipy.integrate.nquad` for this.

Comment: @xnx You might be able to simplify this to just two coordinates, though, (`R = |r_1 + r_2|` and `r = |r_1 - r_2|`), depending on what the OP actually means. Hence my comment.

Comment: If this is possible, then dblquad might be suitable. For six coordinates, the OP should probably go down the Monte Carlo integration route.

Comment: Thanks all!!! r1 and r2 are the radii so i guess that is the same as saying (|r_1|-|r_2|)**k or (|r_1| + |r_2|)**j. Also ye i am integrating over all space, i was just going to multiply the answer by 2pi and pi since there is no dependence upon theta or phi. however i fear i may have to use cartesian coords and integrate over x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2. My issue with this was that my version of scipi does not have the module nquad which is extremely annoying!!!